# CUDA: Copying device data to 2D host array

Tags: cuda

I have a HostMatrix which was declared as:

```
float **HostMatrix
```

I have to copy the content of device matrix , pointed to by `devicePointer` to the 2 dimensional host matrix `HostMatrix`

I tried this

```
for (int i=0; i<numberOfRows; i++){
    cudaMemcpy(HostMatrix[i], devicePointer, numberOfColumns *sizeof(float),
                 cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    devicePointer += numberOfColumns;// so as to reach next row
}
```

But this will be wrong since I am doing this inside a host function, and *devicePointer* can not be manipulated directly in host function as I am doing in last line.

So what will be the correct way to achieve this ?

**Edit**

Oh actually this will work correctly!. But the problem would come while de-allocating the memory as discussed in [my earlier question:  CUDA: Invalid Device Pointer error when reallocating memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824742/cuda-invalid-device-pointer-error-when-reallocating-memory) . So basically the following will be incorrect

```
 for (int i=0; i<numberOfRows; i++){
        cudaMemcpy(HostMatrix[i], devicePointer, numberOfColumns *sizeof(float),
                     cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        devicePointer += numberOfColumns;// so as to reach next row
    }
   cudaFree(devicePointer); //invalid device pointer
```

Comment: Have you tried ? Seems to be good for me. devicePointer points to device memory, but it's still a variable on the host and you **can** do devicePointer += numberOfColumns.

Comment: What do you mean by "`devicePointer` can not be manipulated directly in host function"? Pointers aren't magical unicorns with secret and mystical properties. They are unsigned integers with enough bits to hold the value of an address in memory. Nothing more than that. Of course you can "manipulate it" in host code. All that you cannot do is de-reference it, because its value isn't a valid address in the host memory space.

Comment: @talonmies Sorry I got confused.  Now it s clear.  I just want to know how do I free the  allocated memory now. If I use cudaFree it will give error.

Comment: @leo you are correct. Kindly see me Edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to first allocate devicePointer with all the required memory. But then, increasing it all the time is maybe not the easiest idea, since then the free at the end will be broken. Say you have nRows rows of size nCols. Then this should work properly (I didn't try though, but the idea should be ok):

```
float* dPtr;
cudaMalloc(&dPtr, nRows * nCols);
for (int i=0; i< nRows; i++){
    cudaMemcpy(HostMatrix[i], dPtr + i * nCols, nCols * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}
// do whatever you want
cudaFree(dPtr);
```

The issue is that if you keep increasing dPtr, the cudaFree at the end will only be on the "last row" so it's wrong.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes it worked without errors in memory allocation/de-allocation. But why  cudaFree worked even though  it did not get base address as argument (as we incremented the pointer). it is on last row as you said.

Comment: In my case I was incrementing the pointer outside cuda API cudamemcpy  (see my edits), in your case it is inside cudamemcpy. Why your cudaFree worked  and mine did not? Do you want to say that changes (increments) to the pointer will be not visible to the cudaFree in your case? if so why  ?

Comment: @user3891236: I think you need to spend some time learning the basics of C++ programming before going any further with CUDA. Nowhere in this answer is the value of `ptr` changed between the `cudaMalloc` and `cudaFree` calls. If you don't understand why taht is. I doubt anyone here can help you.

Comment: The issue is that you always need to call free (cudaFree or just the usual free on host code) on the pointer you got from cudaMalloc (or just malloc). The thing is that the free needs to know exactly what you want to free (you always need to free the whole array at once), and it can only do that using the original pointer from malloc.  If you give him an incremented version of that pointer, it can't figure out that it also has to free what's before.